# K.gradients gives type error where both arguments are tensors

Tags: keras

On lines 142 and 143 of: https://github.com/nyck33/openai_spinup_my_implements/blob/master/continuous/mountaincar/my_ddpg_ac.py

I have:

```
self.get_action_gradients = K.function(inputs=[self.model.input[0], self.model.input[1], \
            K.learning_phase()], outputs=[action_gradients])
```

Which tells me:
`line 143, in build_model
K.learning_phase()], outputs=[action_gradients])`

`TypeError: Can not convert a list into a Tensor or Operation.`

`action_gradients` are calculated on line 140 via:

```
action_gradients = K.gradients(Q_value, actions)
```

so I did not think that is a problem but when I take the brackets off of the output argument for `K.function` like so:

```
self.get_action_gradients = K.function(inputs=[*self.model.input, \
            K.learning_phase()], outputs=action_gradients)
```

Now I get a slightly different error mentioning `Nonetype` rather than `list`:

```
rning-copied/_1my_imps/continuous/mountaincar/my_ddpg_ac.py", line 143, in build_model

TypeError: Can not convert a NoneType into a Tensor or Operation.
```

Printing out the Q_values and actions show they are tensors:

```
Q_values Tensor("q_values/BiasAdd:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=float32) actions Tensor("actions:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=float32)
```

But printing out the `action_gradients` and `type(action_gradients)` just confuses me more:

```
action_gradients [None]
action_gradients type <class 'list'>
```

calling:  `K.gradients()` on two tensors should work shouldn't it?

This DDPG code is originally from here:  https://github.com/nyck33/autonomous_quadcopter

and I am trying to adapt it for MountainCarContinuous-v0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am very sorry but this was a careless error.  In the critic network I had different pathways for `state` and `action`, joining them right before the Q-value output layer but...

I actually had `state` as the input for both pathways rather than `action` for the action pathway.

So of course, if the `action` is not present in a network, there is no way to use the chain rule to get the dQ(s,a)/da gradient of output w.r.t. actions.

Here is the code for clarification:

```
def build_model(self):
    #lrelu = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)
    #Define input layers
    states = layers.Input(shape=(self.state_size,), name="states")
    actions = layers.Input(shape=(self.action_size,), name="actions")

    #Add hidden layers for state pathway
    net_states = layers.Dense(units=32, use_bias=False)(states)
    net_states = layers.BatchNormalization()(net_states)
    net_states = layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)(net_states)

    net_states = layers.Dense(units=64)(net_states)
    net_states = layers.BatchNormalization()(net_states)
    net_states = layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)(net_states)

    #hidden layers for action
    net_actions = layers.Dense(units=32)(actions) #had (states) here instead
    net_actions = layers.BatchNormalization()(net_actions)
    net_actions = layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)(net_actions)

    net_actions = layers.Dense(units=64)(net_actions)
    net_actions = layers.BatchNormalization()(net_actions)
    net_actions = layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)(net_actions)
```

and the output to console shows that it is no longer a `None` type:

```
action_gradients [<tf.Tensor 'gradients_3/dense_13/MatMul_grad/MatMul:0' shape=(?, 1) dtype=float32>]
```

Edit:  The code works for MtnCarContinuous-v0 environment of openai gym with a modified reward function (incremental based on car position because the final reward is so sparse), over 90 seems to be achieved in 11 episodes.  I rendered so actually saw the car make it to the top on the attempts where score is over 100 below.
Here are the results:

```
episode: 0 score: -41.59034754863541 mean: -41.59 std: 0.0
episode: 1 score: -75.87242108451743 mean: -58.73 std: 17.14
episode: 2 score: 32.01844640263133 mean: -28.48 std: 45.01
episode: 3 score: 132.904319261567 mean: 11.86 std: 80.02
episode: 4 score: 125.81198290946529 mean: 34.65 std: 84.85
episode: 5 score: 84.26163480413017 mean: 42.92 std: 79.63
episode: 6 score: 126.89684490110164 mean: 54.92 std: 79.37
episode: 7 score: 139.18190524840517 mean: 65.45 std: 79.3
episode: 8 score: 100.24481691450521 mean: 69.32 std: 75.56
episode: 9 score: 165.80286734425076 mean: 78.97 std: 77.31
episode: 10 score: 109.29507292352991 mean: 94.05 std: 66.24
episode: 11 score: 209.07900825070152 mean: 122.55 std: 44.84
```

Source code here:  https://github.com/nyck33/openai_my_implements/tree/master/continuous/mountaincar